# Fill in missing values in pandas dataframe using mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, missing-data

```
datetime
2012-01-01    125.5010
2012-01-02    NaN
2012-01-03    125.5010
2013-01-04    NaN
2013-01-05    125.5010
2013-02-28    125.5010
2014-02-28    125.5010
2016-01-02    125.5010
2016-01-04    125.5010
2016-02-28    NaN
```

I  would like to fill in the missig values in this dataframe by using a climatology computed from the dataset i.e fill in missing `28th feb 2016` value by averaging values of `28th feb` from other years. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `month` and `day` and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.fillna.html) [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html):

```
print df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
datetime           
2012-01-01  125.501
2012-01-02  125.501
2012-01-03  125.501
2013-01-04  125.501
2013-01-05  125.501
2013-02-28  125.501
2014-02-28  125.501
2016-01-02  125.501
2016-01-04  125.501
2016-02-28  125.501
```

Comment: I have a related query to your solution. plz see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979083/retaining-a-column-with-all-strings-during-groupby-on-a-pandas-dataframe. In short, doing a groupby-transform, makes some columns disappear.