# Retaining a column with all strings during groupby on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
datetime    col_A   col_B
1/1/2012    125.501  A
1/2/2012    NaN      A
1/3/2012    125.501  A
1/4/2013    NaN      A
1/5/2013    125.501  B
2/28/2013   125.501  B
2/28/2014   125.501  B
1/2/2016    125.501  B
1/4/2016    125.501  B
2/28/2016   NaN      B
```

As per [Fill in missing values in pandas dataframe using mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972297/fill-in-missing-values-in-pandas-dataframe-using-mean), I am filling in col_A missing values like this:

```
df = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

However, when I do this, it makes col_B go away. How can I retain col_B which is all strings?

Comment: On the left hand side you need `df['col_A'] =` instead of just `df=`.  You're replacing the whole dataframe with one column.  Just replace the column.  And it doesn't matter here, but I'd also specify `col_A` on the right hand side rather than depending on `mean` to ignore `col_B` due to being non-numeric

Comment: If I have multiple columns like `col_A`, will this also work: `df[['col_A','col_C']] = ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add `col_A`:

```
df['col_A'] = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day])['col_A'].transform(lambda x: 
                                                                          x.fillna(x.mean()))
print df
              col_A col_B
datetime                 
2012-01-01  125.501     A
2012-01-02  125.501     A
2012-01-03  125.501     A
2013-01-04  125.501     A
2013-01-05  125.501     B
2013-02-28  125.501     B
2014-02-28  125.501     B
2016-01-02  125.501     B
2016-01-04  125.501     B
2016-02-28  125.501     B
```